# spyder 4.0.1 from anaconda does not launch/appear on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

After updating spyder to 4.0.1, the program seems to launch (either from Anaconda Prompt or other method), and its icon will appear on the taskbar as if it were open, but there is no Spyder window to be found.

Then, I uninstalled Anaconda completely, and reinstalled the latest version (Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64). Same problem persists.
spyder is 4.0.1 and spyder-kernels is 1.8.1
Same problem with spyder 4.1.0 e spyder-kernels 1.9.0

Does anyone know about this or have a solution?

Comment: How were you running Spyder? Did you try it in a new/fresh environment?

Comment: @AMC The problem is the same whether I open Spyder via command prompt or via shortcut. I tried not only new environments, both with fully installation of Spyder within the enviroment and only with installation of the spyder-kernels, but also I tried after removing Anaconda completely and reinstalling.

Comment: did you sort out the problem? I am having the same trouble.

Comment: @Tanvir No, I am just using Spyder 3. I'll give Spyder 4 a try in the future - if you have the same problem now I am little confident this is fixed right now.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. open anaconda and go to anaconda prompt. then type,

```
spyder --reset
```

Close anacoda and then open again. Launch spyder from anaconda.

Comment: Thanks. This helped in one circumstance. The issue reappeared later on though. At the nth reinstallation, it worked eventually - sorry but I don't have details on that anymore.